# Is it possible to send multiple HTTP responses for one HTTP request?

Tags: json, http

I have a requirement of sending more than 100 MB(can increase to any limit) of data as JSON object through HTTP response for one HTTP request in C++ code.
As of now, I am able to send it as one complete JSON object of 100 MB. This might not end up successful if there is any network breakdown.

So, is it possible to send the data in chunks as multiple HTTP responses in any HTTP versions till now?
Please share the information available.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Breaking the data into smaller chunks won't help you avoid lost data if there's a network outage.

Comment: No. One request, one response.

Comment: HTTP is built on TCP, which is designed to guarantee delivery anyways. A "network breakdown" is something even TCP can not work around, so you shouldn't try either. If you really want to do the client a favour, you could support [Byte Serving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving). This is what download managers would use to download a file in chunks and retry chunks that failed. If you implement support for partial HTTP requests, it is up to the user to take advantage of them if it suits their needs.

Comment: Thank you, considering I have 10 JSON objects, is it possible to send one JSON object in one chunk of HTTP response by means of concatenating that JSON object with some trailer string like '###'? And the length of each JSON object is unknown.
For example:
{
    "TYPE": "RECORD_PROPERTIES",
    "STATUS": "OK",
}
###

Comment: I'm removing [tag:c++] and [tag:tomcat] from the taglist, as this question is not related to any of them - and they both don't mix well anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can only send one response per request. What you want to do is build support for resuming requests from an offset on the client.

Answer (score 0):

[Chunked_transfer_encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) could be helpful here.